# SQL Left Outer Join vs Inner Join Not equal to

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I want to select the data from table A that doesnt match the following  query. 
In other words, I want everything from table A except for the following records. 
Im assuming its a left join but I am receiving a lot more matches than expected.

```
SELECT distinct  
    a.Address_Direction,
    a.Address_Extension,
    a.Address_Number,
    a.Address_Root,
    a. PHY_ADDR1,
    b.PHY_ADDR1
FROM [RD_GeoCode].[dbo].[PA_Stg_Test2] AS a
inner JOIN [RD_GeoCode].[dbo].[rg_ApplicationData_AllForms_20160401_address] AS b ON 
 B.address_direction = a.address_direction  
and B.address_root  =  a.address_root
and B.address_number = a.address_number
and B.Address_Extension = a.Address_Extension
and b.PHY_ZIPCD = a.PHY_ZIPCD
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the left join and add `Where B.AnyField Is Null`  As commented, B.AnyField has to be a column without Nulls like a primary key or else you will get false positives.

Also be sure that your join condition does not allow duplicates as that will throw your numbers off.

Comment: To add to this: make sure the "AnyField" chosen cannot be null if there is a match; usually by picking the primary key field, or some other column defined as NOT NULL.

Comment: I have 293K rows in table A, 7 million in table B. The inner join matched on 233k.  But that search resulted in over 300k.                                                         I just want to see the remaining 60k.

Comment: The field you are using from the B table must have nulls.  See my updated answer.  If that column in B has no nulls it is not possible to get more than the 60k you are after.

Comment: Oops, I had my tables on the wrong side. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Along with left join, you have to check if corresponding entries from B is null. Try the following query:

```
SELECT distinct   a.Address_Direction, a.Address_Extension, a.Address_Number, a.Address_Root, a. PHY_ADDR1, b.PHY_ADDR1
FROM [RD_GeoCode].[dbo].[PA_Stg_Test2] AS a
LEFT JOIN [RD_GeoCode].[dbo].[rg_ApplicationData_AllForms_20160401_address] AS b ON 
 B.address_direction = a.address_direction  
AND B.address_root  =  a.address_root
AND B.address_number = a.address_number
AND B.Address_Extension = a.Address_Extension
AND b.PHY_ZIPCD = a.PHY_ZIPCD
WHERE B.address_number IS NULL
```